# How can I create an array of PFObjects in a relation?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a relation that has several PFObjects. I want to query for this relation and put all of the objects into an array. My code does not seem to do the trick, however, so i was hoping for some help.

Code:

```
 var requestsQuery = PFQuery(className: "Requests")
    requestsQuery.whereKey("requested", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    requestsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    usernames.append(object["requesterUsername"] as! String)
                    receivedOffers.append(object["cardsOffered"] as! [AnyObject])
//ERROR HERE: Could not cast value of type 'PFRelation' (0x13c3c8) to 'NSArray' (0x38a26ab8).

                    receivedRequests.append(object["cardsRequested"] as! [AnyObject])
                }
            }
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: The PFUser.currenUser() is wrong - there should be an objectId and not an entire object! btw. you should tag this question with iOS so more ppl can help you!

Comment: Actually, "requested" is a pointer to the User class, so it works just fine. But thanks for letting me know I forgot to tag iOS!

Comment: What's the `receivedOffers`?

Comment: receivedOffers is an array of type PFObject that I need the PFRelation's PFObjects saved to.